# fullcalendar do not work with vue 2.6.12 and laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add fullcalendar library, version 5.9.0 to my project and how the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue) said I had to do

```js
<script>
import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom' // solves problem with Vite
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'

export default {
  components: {
    fullCalendar: FullCalendar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and in the template part,

```html
<template>
  <full-calendar :options="calendarOptions" />
</template>
```

The issue is the element does not render. The element does not even show in the elements while rendering !!
I've removed all the external libraries but it did not work at all :((
If anyone can help me, I would appreciate that :)

Comment: The documentation uses `<FullCalendar` not `<full-calendar`...I don't know Vue but maybe you need to use the exact name?

Comment: You are right I do no use the exact name but when I use the exact name my code ran into register component name error.

Comment: `components: { FullCalendar: FullCalendar }` instead

Comment: @CodyＧNope ! didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the level of import.
When I change the stage of fullcalendar import on top of all other imports in the project It did work fine.